# Bash scripting know the result of a command

Tags: bash, diff, integration-testing

I am writing a bash script to run an integration test of a tool I am writing.

Basically I run the application with a set of inputs and compare the results with expected values using the diff command line tool.

It's working, but I would like to enhance it by knowing the result of the diff command and print "SUCCESS" or "FAIL" depending on the result of the diff.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if diff file1 file2; then
    echo Success
else
    echo Fail
fi
```

If both files are equal, diff returns 0, which is the return code for `if` to follow `then`. If file1 and file2 differ, diff returns 1, which makes if jump to the `else` part of the construct.

You might want to suppress the output of diff by writing `diff file1 file2 >/dev/null` instead of the above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I had read about $? variable, but I wasn't  sure how Diff used it. 

Thanks. 

Does anyone know if it's possible to diff all files from a directory with another?

I have tried diff dir1/* dir2/* but it didn't work.

Comment: LukeN: Thanks for the hint, I added an explanation.

Fork: I’m glad it worked for you. To diff directories, use the -r (recursive) switch: diff -r dir1 dir2

Answer (score 5):

The `$?` variable holds the result of the last executed command.

Answer (score 2):

Also, in Bash you can `diff` the outputs of commands directly using process substitution:

```
if diff <(some_command arg1) <(some_command arg1) > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "They're the same."
else
    echo "They're different."
fi
```